# Trigger based on text property not working

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Here is the xaml that I am working on:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
</TextBlock>
```

When text = "" I want to clear up the margin. But somehow it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must move `Margin="10,0,0,0"` from *`TextBlock`* to setter of `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" /> 

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Because local value has *`higher precedence`* order over style setters and triggers:

1. Property system coercion.
2. Active animations, or animations with a Hold behavior.

   `3. Local value.`
3. TemplatedParent template properties.
4. Implicit style.

   `6. Style triggers.`
5. Template triggers.

   `8. Style setters.`

...

For more information, please see:

[`MSDN: Dependency Property Value Precedence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I will keep in mind the precedence level in future. Thanks for solving the problem again.